# Override Datatables default search function

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using Datatables (https://datatables.net) on my site and would like to override the default search function with a levenstein method.

I already have the levenstein method in place, but I'm having issues with grabbing the value of the search box to test it. The search box that Datatables adds doesn't have an id or name or anything else I can easily use to target that element.

I can think of 2 ways to solve this:

1. Figure out how to get the search box value (the user-typed value)
2. Figure out how to hide the search box without shutting off searching altogether, and add my own custom input.

Here is what I have.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var search = /* this should be the search box value */;
        var title = data[1];

        return ( title.toLowerCase().levenstein(search.toLowerCase()) < title.length ) ? true : false;
    }
);
```

Can you please help me with either one of the listed options above.

Thank you.

Comment: you can't afaik; the search box only uses the data tables API. well, actually, you might be able to clobber the search method, but the dt-made gui will only work with the API, that's the main thing to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't have an id or name or anything else

Well, yes it does have.  This works for me:

```
$('#myTable_filter input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(e.which);
});
```

Just go to the search box and inspect it (if you don't know how to do that in Chrome, just right click on any element and pick Inspect), and you can see how this works for yourself.  DataTables applies an id (your table name with `_filter` tacked on to it) to the div wrapping the input box, and it's the only input box in the div.  So this selector works.  You'll want to do a `preventDefault` as well, so that the DataTables search doesn't run after the keystroke.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get home. I was able to hide the search box by hiding the #table_filter. Now it's just getting my search to run properly. It seems like my search is running AFTER the default search, so not sure how to stop theirs from running. I'll try the preventDefault() when I get home, but not sure if it'll work because mine seems to be after theirs.

Comment: You might be right.  When you do preventDefault, it stops the key from pressing.  If you fill the search box programmatically after applying your own search routine, that might fire the keypress event over again...

Comment: Also, have a look at [the DataTables search event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/search), which fires before redrawing the table but after applying search criteria to the underlying data.  In this, you could probably prevent default, undo the key that applied the search, apply your own search, and redraw the table.  You could also prevent the jitter of putting the character in the search box twice by grabbing the character on keypress and preventing it.

Comment: I tried using on keypress, but it doesn't seem to work, at least with the code I put in place. I had to use `$('#search').val($('#search').val() + e.key)` to set the input, and that was only somewhat working. On top of that, keypress doesn't seem to pick up the backspace keypress event, so it kept the previous search results.

Comment: Besides that, it's still running the original search, but I think that's because in the keypress method, I tell it `table.search( search_value ).draw(); ` If I knew how to remove and add data to the table (like getting the data(), modifying it, then setting the data() ), then I would do that instead of a search, but there doesn't seem to be a way to set the data after the instantiation of the table.